# CSS nth-child on nested divs with different classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, background-color

I have nested divs and I am trying to alternate the background color and the border size.

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="white-bg-alt">
    <div class="white-bg">
      <p class="colored-p">FirstPart</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="white-bg-alt">
    <div class="white-bg">
      <p class="colored-p">SecondPart</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="white-bg-alt">
    <div class="white-bg">
      <p class="colored-p">ThirdPart</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to make the background color to gray when odd .white-bg-alt .white-bg and white when even.

I also want the p.colored-p to be white when .white-bg-alt .white-bg is odd and gray when even.

Here is the CSS I have - but not working, it either gives me all white, or if I modify it, it gives all gray, but not ALTERNATING.

```
.white-bg-alt .white-bg:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #EAEAE3;
  border-top: 0px;
}
.white-bg-alt .white-bg:nth-child(even) {
  border-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.white-bg-alt .white-bg:nth-child(odd) .colored-p {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.white-bg-alt .white-bg:nth-child(even) .colored-p {
  background-color: #EAEAE3;
}
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? I was able to do it with Javascript but I'd rather not do any styling inside javascript.

Comment: `:nth-child`, as well as `:nth-of-type`, only count elements with the ***same*** parent element. They ***must*** be siblings.

Comment: Do you mind giving an example? Examples, I've seen online don't seem useful or intuitive.

Comment: All `:nth-child` asks is: **Am I the n-th child of my parent?** Your code is a perfect example, check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are targetting the wrong element for `nth-child`. Currently you are targetting `.white-bg` but that will always be *odd* because there is only one of this element within its scope.

Instead you want to alternate between the `.white-bg-alt` element.

So a simple change to the following will solve your problem:

```
.white-bg-alt:nth-child(odd) .white-bg {
  background-color: #EAEAE3;
  border-top: 0px;
}
.white-bg-alt:nth-child(even) .white-bg {
   border-bottom: 2px;
   background-color: #FFF;
}
.white-bg-alt:nth-child(odd) .white-bg .colored-p {
   background-color: #FFF;
}
.white-bg-alt:nth-child(even) .white-bg .colored-p {
  background-color: #EAEAE3;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `white-bg-alt` is odd/even element not the `white-bg` element

```css
.white-bg-alt:nth-child(odd) .white-bg {
  background-color: #EAEAE3;
  border-top: 0px;
}
.white-bg-alt:nth-child(even) .white-bg {
  border-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.white-bg-alt:nth-child(odd) .white-bg .colored-p {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.white-bg-alt:nth-child(even) .white-bg .colored-p {
  background-color: #EAEAE3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="white-bg-alt">
    <div class="white-bg">
      <p class="colored-p">FirstPart</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="white-bg-alt">
    <div class="white-bg">
      <p class="colored-p">SecondPart</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="white-bg-alt">
    <div class="white-bg">
      <p class="colored-p">ThirdPart</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.white-bg` is always the first child in its scope, so it's always odd.

Try this instead:

```css
.white-bg-alt:nth-child(odd) .white-bg {
  background-color: #EAEAE3;
  border-top: 0px;
}
.white-bg-alt:nth-child(even) .white-bg {
  border-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.white-bg-alt:nth-child(odd) .white-bg .colored-p {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.white-bg-alt:nth-child(even) .white-bg .colored-p {
  background-color: #EAEAE3;
}
```

This applies the `:nth-child` selector to the `.white-bg-alt` div, which has multiple of its type in its scope.

Answer (score 0):

`:nth-child`, as well as `:nth-of-type`, only count elements with the same parent element. They must be siblings. But since your `.white-bg-alt` all have the same parent elements, you can go with those:

```
.white-bg-alt:nth-child(odd) .white-bg {
  background-color: #EAEAE3;
  border-top: 0px;
}
.white-bg-alt:nth-child(even) .white-bg {
  border-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.white-bg-alt:nth-child(odd) .white-bg .colored-p {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.white-bg-alt:nth-child(even) .white-bg .colored-p {
  background-color: #EAEAE3;
}
```